# How can I convert a string to a number in xpath to run a calculation against it?

Tags: xslt, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

**The Goal**
I'm trying to:

1) scrape all instances of price on a page;

2) find the count of prices to get the count of products on a page; 3) calculate the average price.

**Why I'm Doing This**
I want to drop the `xpath` expression into Screaming Frog to extract the count and avg into separate columns when I crawl the site.

**Where I'm Stuck**
I can't calculate the avg b/c the prices are strings, not integers.

**Contrived Ex**
Since I can't share my real ex, I've replicated the issue with a scrape of this Hipmunk query: `https://www.hipmunk.com/flights#f=NYC;t=SEA;d=2019-11-08;r=2019-11-10;is_search_for_business=false.`

The xpath I'm using to grab the prices: `//div[@class = 'FlightPrice']`

You can see from the Results pane in the screenshot below, it works swimmingly.

[screenshot of functional xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DFKf.png)

Is it possible to convert the currency strings to an integer so I can run calculations on them? I tried wrapping it in a number() function but just got an `NaN error`. Not sure if it's because of the $s.

Comment: Please post your example code (input, your current attempt and the expected result)  **as code** within your question.

Comment: If you're using Scrapy, why don't you extract the strings and convert them using float('number as a string')?

Comment: FYI, this can also be done with xpath 2.0, but AFAIK, Scrapy only supports xpath 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did post the code as well as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

float the item or variable. put it in the parenthesis below and you can use it in an equation

float()

Comment: "_float()_" doesn't work for me, "_number()_" does.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t do the conversion in XPath, you extract the string with XPath and parse it afterwards.

For prices, I recommend that you use [price-parser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/price-parser).